# Passing Array Data between PHP and Javascript is Undefined

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array

I have an associative PHP array I need to access in Javascript to check the value of `manufacturer`. I am currently outputting this inline on the page, then reading in a separate JS file.

```
<?php
$carsData = array();
foreach ($cars as $car) {
    $carsData[] = ['id' => $car->id, 'title' => $car->title, 'manufacturer' => $car->manufacturer];
}
$carsDataString = json_encode($carsData);
?>
<script>
carsData = <?php echo $carsDataString . ';';?>
</script>
```

This works so far - the source code shows exactly as I'd expect:

```
carsData = [{"id":2,"title":"Astra","manufacturer":"2"},{"id":3,"title":"Tepee","manufacturer":"3"},{"id":4,"title":"C4 Grand","manufacturer":"4"},{"id":5,"title":"Civic","manufacturer":"5"},{"id":6,"title":"Jazz","manufacturer":"5"}];
```

In my so far feeble attempts to read this in JS, I have the following:

```
        $.each(carsData, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key['manufacturer']);
        });
```

In my console, this is outputting `undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined`. If I execute `carsData` in the console, I see the objects exactly as I would expect.

So what am I doing wrong? I need to be able to take this and do the following:

```
        $.each(carsData, function(key, value) {
            if (key['manufacturer'] = 5 {
                $('#manufacturer' + key['manufacturer'].show();
            }
        });
```

Please note I have simplified it as the value of '5', because this value actually comes from another script and is printing 5 there as I expect.

Comment: `carsData = <?php echo $carsDataString;?>;` Need to add the final `;` to make the js valid

Comment: As @RiggsFolly, that is what was missing, and the [devtools] Console would have shown a javascript parse error in regards to that. From there, Ehsan's answer pointed towards the other mistake of using `key` instead of `value`.

Comment: My bad, copy/paste errror. The `;` is there. Updated OP.

Answer (score 1):

To make the js valid you need to add a `;` to the end of this line

```
carsData = <?php echo $carsDataString;?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$.each(carsData, function(key, value) {
            console.log(value['manufacturer']);
        });
```

Comment: Both this answer and the one provided by RiggsFolly has solved the problem. Doh!

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="javascript">
carsData = new Array(<?php echo implode(",",$carsDataString);?>);
</script>
```

Comment: Yikes man, no. The output as pure JSON is correct. This above makes a complete mess of things.

Comment: Why wrap a json string in an array?